# Python identify in which interval the numbers are

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, intervals

I would like to run a `for` loop in Python that checks, given a certain amount of intervals, for each element of the loop, in which interval it is. For instance:

```
interval_1 = [1; 10]
interval_2 = [11; 58]
```

I was looking for a more elegant solution than a large `if/elif/else` condition, for instance my idea was to load an excel worksheet containing `n` couples of numbers corresponding to the interval extremities, and use a function that finds me for in which interval my number is.

Does a similar function exist in Python? Or eventually how could this be done?

Comment: What is an "element of a loop"?

Comment: If your intervals are evenly spaced, a histogram function might work, for example: [numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy` has nice support for this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) without having to write a `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([0.2, 6.4, 3.0, 1.6])
bins = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 10.0])
cats = np.digitize(data, bins)
cats
# array([1, 4, 3, 2])
```

If you insist on a `for` loop, just iterate over the elements to bin, and the bins:

```
data = [0.2, 6.4, 3.0]
bins = [(0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 4.0), (4.0, 10.0)]  # assumed (lower, upper] format
cats = []

for elem in data:
    for idx, bounds in enumerate(bins, start=1):
        if bounds[0] < elem <= bounds[1]:
            cats.append(idx)
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError('No bin for {}'.format(elem))
```

The above uses tuples to specify the bin ranges (like your example), but that's not technically necessary (e.g. the `numpy` code). You could store just the cutoffs and compare adjacent elements from `cutoffs[:-1]`.

Comment: Thank you I used this method and it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that should run faster if you have a very large list of ranges. It uses python's `bisect` module to do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to quickly find the range in which the item belongs.

For this example I'm using the ranges 2..5, 7..9 and 13..13.

The code checks whether all numbers from 0 to 14 is in one of the supplied ranges.

### Code:

```
from bisect import *

ranges = [2, 5, 7, 9, 13, 13]   # Using this convention: 2..5, 7..9, 13..13. Assume ranges inclusive.
for item in range(15):
    valid = False
    L = (bisect_left(ranges, item) // 2) * 2
    if L+1 < len(ranges):
        valid = ranges[L] <= item and ranges[L + 1] >= item
    print(item, valid)
```

### Output:

```
0 False
1 False
2 True
3 True
4 True
5 True
6 False
7 True
8 True
9 True
10 False
11 False
12 False
13 True
14 False
```

Comment: If `valid` is `True`, `L // 2` is the index number of the range it belongs to.