# Binning data in Python

Tags: python, data-analysis, quantile, binning

I'm working very hard to understand how to bin data in Python.  So far I have worked out how to get the edges using:

```
edges = pylab.hist(data, bins=10)[1]
```

I'm not sure if this is the most ideal method, but it worked!  Gives me a list of 11 numbers needed to make 10 bins.  Problem is that I'm at a loss as how to then classify data into bins.  I tried using:

```
digitized = np.digitize(data, edges)
```

But that just gave me an error, "*ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity*".  I need to make bins somehow before using pandas value_counts (I have that part down already as well).

Any help would super appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python identify in which interval the numbers are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479374/python-identify-in-which-interval-the-numbers-are)  The answer to this question shows you how to do this.

Comment: I already tried that, I should have included that in here so it wouldn't get shot down straight away.  Sorry.

Comment: It would be useful to include a toy example of data

Comment: Actually that line did work.  I answered my own question before I asked it, but didn't realize.  Another bit of code was causing the error.  I feel dumb :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

```
digitized = np.digitize(data, edges)
```